# Now that Ember.View is deprecated, how does one access event objects for events triggered in the top-level application.hbs template?

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading an application that customizes `Ember.View` for the top-level `application.hbs`. There I have an event handler that needs access to the `event` object that gets passed in:

```
ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  click(event) {
    // Need event here.
  }
});
```

Now that `Ember.View` is deprecated, I'm not sure how to replace this logic.

I could add an action handler at some div that would capture the event of interest in `application.hbs`:

```
<div {{action "topLevelClick"}}>
   ...
</div>
```

But although this fires, I don't have access to the `event` object.

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions declared as DOM event handlers *do* pass the event:

```
{{!-- application/template.hbs --}}
<div onclick={{action 'topLevelClick'}}>Click Me</div>

// application/controller.js
actions: {
  topLevelClick(event) {
    console.log('topLevelClick', event);
  }
}
```

This works on Ember 1.13.13; I haven't tried 1.13.11, though it also supports these kinds of event handlers in general.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't registering it as a DOM event handler. Thanks. It works on 1.13.11.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the action handler receives the first parameter of the event listener, the event object the browser passes to the handler.
Therefore, in your action you can get the event as the first parameter.
Let say in your controller for application, you have action as:

```
actions: {
    topLevelClick: function(event){
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

this will print on the console, the actual browser event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the docs. But at least in the version I'm using, `1.13.11`, this doesn't work. I'm looking for a transitional path while I upgrade my app to 2.x. When I add the action handler you describe, the argument is `undefined`. Should this work with `1.13.x`? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The above solution is for the latest version.